# node module chai for testing set {'content-type': 'text/plain'}

Tags: node.js, npm, chai

I want to test a negative scenario where if the the 'content-type' in the header of a request is set wrongly, I want the user to be sent the right http-error-code. However, node module chai is not throwing error upon making 'conent-type' other than appliction/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
describe('header checks for "content-type"', function() {
    it('it should return "Request does not contain correct \'content-type\'"', function(done) {
        chai.request(server)
        chai.request(server)
            .post('/a/b/c')
            .set('content-type', 'text/plain')
            .send({
                "an": 107,
                "mn": 983
            })
            .end(function(error, response, body) {
                response.should.have.status(415);
            });
    });
});
```

So, http-status 415 is for unsupported media type, That is what I want to test for, but, I get the following error.

> 1) header checks for "content-type" it should return "Request does
>   not contain correct 'content-type'":
>        TypeError: "string" must be a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer
>         at Function.byteLength (buffer.js:362:11)
>         at Test.Request.end (/project/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:716:84)
>         at Context. (abc.js:38:14)